# Query Rewriting with URL Parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot get the query rewriting to work as expected. The desired outcome is for requests going to `wpsite.com/foo/bar/2/` to be rewritten as `wpsite.com/foo/bar/?my_id=2`.

functions.php

```
// Add custom URL parameters
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "my_id";
  return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );

// Add rewrite for my_id
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^foo/bar/([0-9]+)/?', 'foo/bar/?my_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

bar.php

```
$my_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "my_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

var_dump($my_id);
```

When I call `/foo/bar/?my_id=2` I see `2`, when I use `/foo/bar/2/`, I do not.

**Update**

After flushing the cache the result *improved*. However, regardless of the passed parameter (`3`, `256205`), `$my_id` comes back as `1`.

`wpsite.com/foo/bar/?my_id=2` shows `2`

`wpsite.com/foo/bar/2/` shows `1`

Comment: When you run `/foo/bar/2/` does it redirect at all? Also... have you flushed the caches ;)

Comment: @ChrisHappy I just re-flushed caches and doing better. But now when I call `/foo/bar/527/` I'm just seeing `1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191802/discussion-between-chris-happy-and-kermit).

Comment: The `$matches[1]` is only going to work for rewrite rules which correspond to the WordPress's `index.php` file. But in your case, the second parameter for the `add_rewrite_rule()` doesn't start with `index.php`, which means the rewrite rule would be written as a "real" Apache rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file and not saved into the database. Hence (as you've figured it out), use `$1` for "real" rewrite rules. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by changing `$matches[1]` to `$1`:

```
// Add rewrite for my_id
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^foo/bar/([0-9]+)/?', 'foo/bar/?my_id=$1', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

And of course flushing cache.